# Failed to connect redis docker via 172.17.0.2:6379

Tags: python, docker, sockets, redis

I am new to redis and docker, and I tried to take some simple practices on this, on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I create a container call `my_redis` and know its address is `172.17.0.2` via `docker inspect` command.

However, when I try to run python REPL, with `redis.Redis(host='172.17.0.2, port=6379)`, and run the command `r.set(...)`, I received `Error 111 connecting to 172.17.0.2:6379. Connection failed.`

It seems that my connection is rejected.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple command you can use to create a Redis container:

```
docker run --rm -p 6379:6379 redis
```

You can then access Redis from your host at `localhost:6379`. Here
`-p 6379:6379` means map the host's port 6379 to the same port inside the container; `--rm` means delete the container and its data on exit.

If you want to go a bit further and save Redis data between container restarts, you could use `docker-compose`. Create `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  redis:
    image: "redis"
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - redis-data:/data
volumes:
  redis-data:
```

Run it with `docker-compose up`. With this configuration, Redis data will be saved between restarts.

Comment: @Anthon Thanks for your help! I have solved it myself. The problem came from I start my container in interactive mode, so I started a Bash shell with docker. It seems that it isolate itself (not sure if it is right). Anyway, I can continue my work now. Thanks anyway.